# Manga about boy with black hair who has the power to summon spirits

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for a manga, it's fantasy but I'm not sure if it's Isekai. The story starts with the birth of the mc who he is seen as a bad omen child due to his black hair and eyes. In the land he lives in, black is seen as the color of death. I'm pretty sure he was born from either a wealthy or royal family but is locked up due to his circumstances. At some point he escapes and I think he's adopted by a group of people. The MC has the power to summon and create spirits to fight, I think one of the spirits he creates are twins that wield rifles but i might be wrong. The chapter I last remember has the MC and his companions going up against a chimera in a beastman village.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, was there a female lead? If so, do you recall her hair colour?

Comment: I think it was mostly black and white. There is a female lead but I do not remember her hair color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this ***[The Summoner Who Was Despised as 'Shunned Child'](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/imiko-to-yobareta-shoukanshi)***...?

> There is a world where there is no end to those who seek spirits and those who hunt spirits. In this world, there was a baby who was abandoned by his real parents as a detester to black hair and black eyes. The name of this child is Wilm. Picked up by the spirits, he grew into a summoner who protects his beloved sisters and the beloved village. "I won't tolerate the guy who dares to touch my family!" The blunt and summoned beast sisters shake the world.

As a baby, the main character was abandoned in a forest by his parents due to his black hair and eyes, which his parents believe mean he is damned and will bring disaster to those around him. He's subsequently found and adopted by female spirits who live in a secret village hidden in that forest. As a young man, he's fiercely loyal to his adoptive family, and uses his summoning powers to protect their village from mercenaries and such.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's the one thank you

Answer (score 1):

***[Kuro no Souzou Shoukanshi - Tenseisha no Hangyaku](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/xd63c0j/kuro-no-souzou-shoukanshi-tenseisha-no-hangyaku)***.

> Due to a god's mistake, high schooler Tsuguna died before his time. In exchange, the god agreed to do him a favor in his next life. Tsuguna is reborn to a noble household in a world with magic. He has an unusual form of magic that he requested from the god, the ability to create summoned creatures. However, his dark Japanese hair and eyes mark him as a cursed child in this new world, and his powers are slow to appear. He's kept in a dark basement where he reads his family's books, until one day he finally uncovers the key to his powers. Finally, he can set off into the world with his summoned companion to level up his skills!